# remove value attribute of input element using CSS only

Tags: html, css

I have a "Submit" button which I'm trying to replace with an image

```
<input type="submit" value="Continue" />
```

I can't modify the HTML, and can't use JavaScript. I only have access to the CSS.

Is it possible to remove the word "Continue" (`value` attribute) using CSS only?

**EDIT**

I've actually been able to style the button with the image already. I now want to remove the "Continue" button. I've done it by setting the `text-indent` value to negative, which was suggested here a while ago, but was deleted. I wonder who posted it so I could accept it as the answer.

Comment: no 1 actually understood his question he doesn't want to style it, he want's the continue word to be removed using CSS

Comment: @Mr.Alien "I'm trying to replace with an image".

Comment: @SpaceBeers your's is correct ;) btw can use css content ?

Comment: Not supported in some versions on IE. 8 I think.

Comment: Please, don't do the `text-indent`, it's a hack. Use `color: transparent` instead.

Comment: @Mr.Alien `content` didn't work

Comment: @amn - I'll second that - http://luigimontanez.com/2010/stop-using-text-indent-css-trick/

Comment: @amn pretty simple solution, post it as an answer

Comment: @Obay `content` currently **only** works with `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, it doesn't yet work they way many of us would want it to. However, that's part of what CSS3 is addressing already, but as far as I know only Opera currently is able to understand it. The rest are coming, hopefully. An argument is of course that no styling should ever override document content, hence perhaps such a late introduction of this feature, but opinions may differ.

Comment: @Obay - text-indent is spammy and best avoided.

Comment: @Mr.Alien is right, I just want to remove the "Continue" word since I've already been able to set the background image

Comment: @SpaceBeers I've removed `text-indent` and used `color` as suggested by @amn.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: this is a **bad** answer -- I hope you know it too, deep down in your heart. If you scoff at my fair warning, aliens from CeSSei 8 will abduct you for box modeling you in 4 dimensions. Upvote this answer at own risk. I wrote it in what now seems another life, and it looks into the depths of my soul every time I read it. I weep for the Web. **You have been warned.**

I can't imagine why someone would need to remove a value of a control *using CSS only*. I certainly have never needed to even consider doing that.

Regardless, an alternative to `font-size: 0` which makes using `em` and  `ex` units for the element impossible, is to make the text render with transparent "brush", effectively not rendering it at all:

```
color: transparent;
```

Note that the above rule applied to an input element has *no effect* on the color of the placeholder text in the element.

This solution, as most such "hacks" go, has a number of issues -- you would probably want to at least add `user-select: none` along with the above rule, to disable user selection of text, because selecting it would expose it against the solid background color of the selection, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: i do not think this is a useful and correct answer because it will also make transparent the olaceholder, in case u need .

Comment: @Alejo_Blue I have updated the answer to include the statement on the placeholder text, which is unaffected by the suggested rule.

Comment: just awsome & simple

Answer (score 5):

```
input[type="submit"] {
  font-size:0;
  width:120px;
  height:30px;
  background: url('dir/image.png') no-repeat left top;
  border: none;
}
```

This will do the trick. Remember your image path is relative to the stylesheet.

Answer (score 3):

Using `font-size: 0`:

```
input[type="submit"] {
    font-size:0;
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    background:red; /** or `background: url('some.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;` */
    border:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/c9DbsO4u)**

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [SpaceBeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936643/spacebeers)'s answer, it is good to use a negative `text-indent` and remove the text, if there's any.

```
input[type="submit"] {
  font-size:0;
  width:120px;
  height:30px;
  background: url('dir/image.png') no-repeat left top;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -99em;
}
```

#### And this is the right way, almost all the places suggest. Also, you can find a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/6MKKh/

Comment: I'd steer well clear of text-indent - http://luigimontanez.com/2010/stop-using-text-indent-css-trick/